# chkdsk exits/quits in the middle of stage 2

Tags: chkdsk

I am trying to fix a external HDD, running chkdsk with /f or /r or /x, it doesnt matter which one, will always result in exit during stage 2.

[image]

Why does it exit without a message or anything?
I need it to get to like stage 4 so it can fix the errors...

Comment: Did you try to do this with windows running, OR did you boot from your windows DVD, select repair my computer, and then **command prompt**.  Then run chkdsk /f c:   (or whatever drive letter it is, as it maybe be different in this mode)

Comment: tthis drive doesnt have an OS files so I didnt try that

Comment: The DVD is self contained and your external can be blank for all it cares.  Part 2 try **chkdsk /x /B f:**  If that fails you may have to use SpinRite at www.grc.com to do a physical scan/re-allocation of bad sectors.  Can you copy the data off,reformat, and put the data back?

Comment: how can i copy the data off? like how to get access to it

Comment: If your file system is not accessible the normal way, then you need a scanning tool.  For example PhotoRec by cgsecurity.  It will take a while and probably resurrect files you deleted and mangle some of the file names but it gets a lot back.  R-Studio from the paid side of the isle.  Recovery programs will not put the data back on the original drive make sure you current drive has enough room or get another one.

Comment: If the hard drive is to bad you will have to pre-treat it with spinrite from grc.com or possible mhdd